# Generating interaction variables in R dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a way - other than a for loop - to generate new variables in an R dataframe, which will be all the possible 2-way interactions between the existing ones?
i.e. supposing a dataframe with three numeric variables V1, V2, V3, I would like to generate the following new variables:

```
Inter.V1V2 (= V1 * V2) 
Inter.V1V3 (= V1 * V3)
Inter.V2V3 (= V2 * V3)
```

Example using for loop :

```
x <- read.table(textConnection('
   V1 V2 V3 V4
1  9   25   18
2  5   20   10
3  4   30   12
4  4   34   16'
), header=TRUE)

dim.init <- dim(x)[2]
for (i in 1: (dim.init - 1) ) {
        for (j in (i + 1) : (dim.init) ) {
                x[dim(x)[2] + 1]    <- x[i] * x[j]
                names(x)[dim(x)[2]] <- paste("Inter.V",i,"V",j,sep="")

        }
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here is a one liner for you that also works if you have factors:

```
> model.matrix(~(V1+V2+V3+V4)^2,x)
  (Intercept) V1 V2 V3 V4 V1:V2 V1:V3 V1:V4 V2:V3 V2:V4 V3:V4
1           1  1  9 25 18     9    25    18   225   162   450
2           1  2  5 20 10    10    40    20   100    50   200
3           1  3  4 30 12    12    90    36   120    48   360
4           1  4  4 34 16    16   136    64   136    64   544
attr(,"assign")
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Excellent! You could also get rid of the irrelevant (in our case) intercept 
 model.matrix(~(V1+V2+V3+V4)^2-1,x)

Comment: right you are. or for the fully general case as.data.frame(model.matrix(~ .^2-1,x))

Comment: What if you have numeric variables, rather than factors?  Will this method still work?

Comment: This works for numeric variables too. Note that it doesn't give self-interaction terms like `V1*V1`.

Answer (score 15):

Here you go, using `combn` and `apply`:

```
> x2 <- t(apply(x, 1, combn, 2, prod))
```

Setting the column names can be done with two `paste` commands:

```
> colnames(x2) <- paste("Inter.V", combn(1:4, 2, paste, collapse="V"), sep="")
```

Lastly, if you want all your variables together, just `cbind` them:

```
> x <- cbind(x, x2)
>   V1 V2 V3 V4 Inter.V1V2 Inter.V1V3 Inter.V1V4 Inter.V2V3 Inter.V2V4 Inter.V3V4
1  1  9 25 18          9         25         18        225        162        450
2  2  5 20 10         10         40         20        100         50        200
3  3  4 30 12         12         90         36        120         48        360
4  4  4 34 16         16        136         64        136         64        544
```

Comment: Very nice! Is there a way to also change the column names, according to the example, using apply?

Comment: If you are just going to use these interactions in models that take formula, such as lm or glm, you don't need to generate the variables.  See: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Formulae-for-statistical-models

Comment: @Tristan : Ok, I know that when using models this can be done using R's modeling formulae. What I wanted to do is to generate interaction variables to use them as predictors in classification problems.

Comment: Amazing - if column names of data are unknown at the time of writing the code this is exactly what to use!

Answer (score 3):

I think this question should be complemented with the `poly/polym` function, which goes futher: it generates not only interactions between the variables, but its power until the selected degree. And [orthogonal iteractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials), which may be very usefull.

The directly solution to the asked problem would be:

```
> polym(x$V1, x$V2, x$V3, x$V4, degree = 2, raw = T)
     1.0.0.0 2.0.0.0 0.1.0.0 1.1.0.0 0.2.0.0 0.0.1.0 1.0.1.0 0.1.1.0 0.0.2.0 0.0.0.1 1.0.0.1 0.1.0.1 0.0.1.1 0.0.0.2
[1,]       1       1       9       9      81      25      25     225     625      18      18     162     450     324
[2,]       2       4       5      10      25      20      40     100     400      10      20      50     200     100
[3,]       3       9       4      12      16      30      90     120     900      12      36      48     360     144
[4,]       4      16       4      16      16      34     136     136    1156      16      64      64     544     256
attr(,"degree")
 [1] 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2
```

The columns 4, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13 has the requested in the question. Other columns have other kinds of interactions. If you would like to get orthogonal interactions, just set `raw = FALSE`.