# R error when modifying model variables: "model frame and formula mismatch in model.matrix()"

Tags: r, runtime-error

I wanted to write a function which takes a model, calculates the vif, and returns a new model with the collinear variables removed. Here's my code:

```
remodel_vif <- function(mdl, vif_cutoff){

bad_x <- mdl %>% car::vif() %>% {which(. > vif_cutoff)}
new_df <- mdl$model %>% dplyr::select(.,-bad_x) 
return(lm(new_df))

}
```

If I execute the function, it throws an error:

```
 data <- data.frame(c1 = c(1,5,3,2,1,7,7,7,6,5), c2 = 0.3*c(1:10), c3 = 0.5*c(1:10)+rnorm(10), c4 = 0.1*rnorm(10))
 remodel_vif(data,2.0)
```

`Error in model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) : 
  model frame and formula mismatch in model.matrix()`

However, if I make this change in the function:

```
new_df <- mdl$model %>% dplyr::select(.,-bad_x) %>% as.matrix() %>% as.data.frame()
```

then it works:

```
> remodel_vif(lm(data),2)

Call:
lm(formula = new_df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           c4  
      2.700        4.268
```

Note: I'm aware this function doesn't make much sense and isn't very useful - I'm just wondering what causes the error to appear, and why transforming it back and forth like that helps.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399090/r-how-to-update-model-frame-after-reducing-model-formula) here on SE, but I don't see how it's relevant: I'm not using the original model object's parameters - I only extract its underlying data frame and modify it. I don't see how there could be any interactions from the removed variables hanging around...